# Graphing a function with an internal transcendental equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

this is my first post here and I am newer at Mathemtaica, so be easy on me. 
I have a transcendental equation that keeps crashing Mathematica or producing `{{}}`when I attempt to solve it.

Here is my simplified formula:

```
a = (6.821 10^23 + 4.446 10^11 z)/(1.057 10^11 + 0.101 z);
b = (4.971*10^23 + 9.793*10^11 1 z)/(1.057*10^11 + 0.1010 z);
z := (x/(9.84 10^13 (b - 2 a))) (Exp[4.92*10^-13 ((b - 2 a) 4)] - 1)

y = 12.083 ((5.186 10^10 z)/(1.057 10^11 + 0.101 z) - (1.459 10^12)/(
 1.0570 10^11 + 1.111 z));
```

`y[x_]` is the formula I want to be able to plot.

I've searched SE for similar problems and it seems like I should be using `FindRoot` or `NSolve`

So

```
NSolve[z == 0, {z}]
```

Gives:`$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded`

and

```
FindRoot[z == 0, {z, 0}]
```

Crashes Mathematica. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `a` and `b` depend on `z`, but then in your third line `z` depends again on `a` and `b`. Are you sure, these are the right expressions?

Comment: You have $a(z)$, $b(z)$, $z(a,b,x)$ and $y(z)$. How do you suppose to solve $z(z)$?

Comment: Once `a` and `b` are inserted into `z`, `z` becomes `z(x,z)`. Then `z(x,z)` goes into `y(z)`. Producing a `y(x,z)`.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't define things this way, because *Mathematica* will keep updating the values, because each of your `a`, `b`, `z`, and `y` all have definitions. Instead, maybe try replacement rules. But I don't understand your last comment: You want to plot `y[x]`, but `y` is a function of both `x` and `y`. Is it that you want to plot `y` as a function of `x` for `z = 0`?

Comment: Also, by the way, the fact that you have very larger numbers (e.g. 10^11) and very small numbers (e.g. 10^-13) means that you are likely going to have some numerical issues. It would be worthwhile either re-formulating your problem or redefining your variables by scaling them so that the coefficients are all closer to 1.

Comment: `z(x,z)` doesn't make sense. Maybe try giving in plain terms what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the equations in order to make it appear simpler, but I might have made a mistake.  Let me revise my formulas.

Comment: Sorry, now I get what you want to do. Your formulas are not the problem, the main problem seems to be the solution of the nonlinear equation `nleq = z - (x .... a(z) .... b(z)) == 0` for `z` depending on `x`. `Reduce` is not able to do this, not even with exact coefficients. For `NSolve` you would need to insert something for `x`, in order to get something for `z`, do you know what I mean? Do you have any guesses for the ranges for `x` or `z`? That would help.

Comment: @MauricioLobos This doesn't appear to be correct, the definition of `z` already gives recursion error.

Comment: @Feyre Sorry, of course your are right, he should define an implicit equation `eq = z - (x ... a .... b) == 0` in order to avoid the recursion error.

Comment: `x` should go from 0 to 12,000 (W/cm2), I am not sure the range of `z`. It is possible with some physics "handwaving" to make `z` into a function of x, `z(x)`, but it takes some big assumptions that restricts the model's effectiveness. So I would like to solve the transcendental,  `z(x, a(z), b(z)` into  `z(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

So, the big numbers are kind of a problem, but you can try this. First, in order to eliminate the recursion error, define an equation `eq` for the implicit definition of $z(x)$ or $x(z)$

```
a = (6.821 10^23 + 4.446 10^11 z)/(1.057 10^11 + 0.101 z);
b = (4.971*10^23 + 9.793*10^11 1 z)/(1.057*10^11 + 0.1010 z);
eq = (x/(9.84 10^13 (b - 2 a))) (Exp[4.92*10^-13 ((b - 2 a) 4)] - 1) - z == 0;
y = 12.083 ((5.186 10^10 z)/(1.057 10^11 + 0.101 z) - (1.459 10^12)/(1.0570 10^11 + 1.111 z));
```

Now, the equation `eq` sadly can not be solved with Mathematica in respect to z in order to obtain $z(x)$. But it can easily be solved in respect to `x` and you can take a look at it for varying `z`

```
xsol = x /. Solve[eq, x][[1]];
Plot[xsol, {z, -10, 10}]
```

[image: x(z)]

As you can see, for your case, around $z = 0$ it seems to be a linear relation. So, let's take the first-order Taylor approximation, invert it, and then with $z_1(x)$ go into $y(z)$ and get $y_1(x)$ as you wanted (for an approximation). This is what you get for $y_1(x)$

```
xsol1 = Normal[Series[xsol, {z, 0, 1}]];
zsol1 = z /. Solve[xsol1 == x, z][[1]];
ysol1 = y /. z -> zsol1;
Plot[ysol1, {x, -10^20, 10^20}]
```

[image: y_1(x)]